# returning date of file creation in a certain format in Bash

Tags: bash

Is there a way to return the creation date of a file in the following format?
*yyyymmdd_hhmmss (ie 20230124_181920)*

Many thanks for any help

Comment: It depends. See: [What file systems on Linux store the creation time?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/7562/74329)

Comment: Please add to your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: `bash` itself has no way of reporting the creation date of a file, so the question is, what program are you *running* from `bash` that reports the creation date?

Answer (score 1):

With GNU's date and stat command:

```
date -d@"$(stat -c %W file)" '+%Y%m%d_%H%M%S'
```

As people pointed out, availability of creation date info depends on [file]system.

Comment: That worked an absolute treat. They you